# combining filter with copy commands in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg command that changes the PTS of several segments of a video file. the problem is that all the segments are being re encoded (instead of COPY), even the segments that retain the same PTS, and the operation is very slow

```
ffmpeg -i t.mp4 -i y.wav -filter_complex  "[0:v]trim=0.0:60.859,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[0:v]trim=60.859:64.379,setpts=1.2946875*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];[0:v]trim=64.379:70.858,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];[0:v]trim=70.858:72.378,setpts=1.1231231*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v4];[0:v]trim=72.378:,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v5];[0:a]atrim=0.0:60.859,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[0:a]atrim=60.859:64.379,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.7723871590634805[a2];[0:a]atrim=64.379:70.858,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];[0:a]atrim=70.858:72.378,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.8903743498820388[a4];[0:a]atrim=72.378:,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a5];[v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3][v4][a4][v5][a5]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

I tried appending `-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a copy` to the command but i get an error Streamcopy requested for output stream fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Is there a way to do that task without running a separate ffmpeg command for each segment and then concatenating them at the end?

thanks!

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1